# Creating Server/Client service with ESB

Tags: mule, esb, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm interested in the following if it is possible to create Server Client implementation with ESBs. For me it is clear that these are good for web services, however I'm talking about different protocols and implementations.

For example would it be possible to create a Messaging Router which supports on both Server and Client side SMPP protocol ( Stateful TCP based protocol ) which will have to handle many connections on both the Server and the Client side. Persistent connections are also required.

I have an idea to use the ESB as a Router, Protocol translation, field manipulation etc...

So the main question is if something wrapped around the ESB would be a good idea? Preferably looking to use Netty for connection handling and connection mapping. One more requirement would be to be able to make direct connection mapping between the Server and the Client endpoints.

If that would be possible what's the best way to be done, possible usage of J6EE framework/Spring ?

thanks, 
Tiho

Comment: Anyone can help with suggestions here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. SMPP transport is available in WSO2 ESB.

The latest code for the transport can be found from https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/dependencies/transports/1.1.0-wso2v9/modules/sms/

Also, the following 3 blogs explains how to configure the ESB with the SMPP transport. 
http://charith.wickramaarachchi.org/2009/06/axis2-sms-transport.html
http://charith.wickramaarachchi.org/2009/12/invoking-webservices-using-axis2-sms.html
http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/01/wso2-esb-sending-sms-alerts-for-failures.html

Also you can front any kind of BE service with WSO2 ESB via a proxy service and all the configurations can be done using the synapse configuration language which is an XML based language. The ESB has the capablity of writing synapse configurations in the XML editor and as well as the graphical support too is available for creating configurations.